# drawing,the intersection point clears

Tags: ipad, drawing

We are devloping a Drawing app. In that when we draw crossed lines ,the intersection point clears the previously drawn pixels where both lines intersects eachother.We are using setneedsdisplayinrect to refresh the drawing data.

How to over come this issue?

Comment: Try adding a question to your question, they end with a "?". Also, some code showing how you are drawing plus a picture or just more detailed explanation of the problem would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr:** You need to store the previous line segments and redraw them when draw in the same rectangle again.

---

> We are using setneedsdisplayinrect to refresh the drawing data

That is a good thing. Can you see any side effects of doing that? If not, try passing the entire rectangle and see what happens. You will see that only the very last segment is drawn.

Now you know that you need to store and possibly redraw previous line segments (or just their image).

## Naive approach

The first and simplest solution would be to store all the lines in an array and redraw them. You would notice that this will slow down your app *a lot* especially when after having drawn for a while. Also, it doesn't go very well with only drawing what you need

## Only drawing lines inside the refreshed rectangle

You could speed up the above implementation by filtering all the lines in the array to only redraw those that intersect the refreshed rect. This could for example be done by getting the bounding box for the line segment (using `CGPathGetBoundingBox(path)`) and checking if it intersects the refreshed rectangle (using `CGRectIntersectsRect(refreshRect, boundingBox)`).

That would reduce some of the drawing but you would still end up with a very long array of lines and see performance problems after a while.

## Rasterize old line segments

One good way of not having to store all previous lines is to draw them into a bitmap (a separate image context (see `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(...)`)) draw that image before drawing the new line segment. However, that would almost double the drawing you would have to do so it should not be done for every frame.

One thing you could do is to store the last 100 line segments (or maybe the last 1000 or whatever your own performance investigation shows, *you should investigate these things yourself*) and draw the rest into an image. Every time you have a 100 new lines you add them to the image context – by first drawing the image and then drawing the new 100 line – and save that as the new image.

One other thing you could do is to take all the new lines and draw them to the image every time the user lifts their finger. This can work well in combination with the above suggestion.

---

Depending on the complexity of your app you may need one or more of these suggestions to keep your app responsive (which is very important for a drawing app) but investigate first and don't make your solution overly complex if you don't have to.